# Notepad++ Current directory

Tags: java, unix, notepad++

I'm using notepad++ to as editor to my java program.
it is installed in windows..
and i'm doing a program to UNIX (server)..

well i used **NppFTP** plugin to connect my notepad++ to server remotely..
in that case, i can edit java file from server through my machine.

i'm also using **NppExec** plugin to compile my java file.
compiling my java using **NppExec** in my machine is easy.

The problem is i cant set the directory to server.
current directory of my notepad++ is location of installed notepad++
example C:\Program Files\Notepad++..
I'm configuring this location through **cd** command..

compiling java program in server (UNIX) through **NppExec** is so hard to do,
since i can't configure the directory to path of server..
is it possible to used **NppExec** plugin to compile java program from UNIX through my windows?? thanks a lot

Comment: Are you trying to execute programs on server through FTP? It is "File Transfer Protocol". To my understanding it can only do simple file system operations, but running programs remotely is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no, not easily.  Your goal sounds like you want to use **NppExec** to compile your Java program on the remote Unix server.  All that **NppExec** can do is some basic commands PLUS it can run other programs.  If you want to be configuring your Unix server and running any commands on it (including invoking the Java compiler or running your Java program) you should be using SSH. Putty is one among many tools for this:

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

In addition, while Java is cross-platform I would suggest compiling in just one place, probably in the environment you are most comfortable with.  For example, once you start including libraries in your code things can get complicated.  IDEs are designed to help you with this and I might suggest going over to an IDE instead of using Notepad++.

What **NppFTP** is:

It is just a simple add-in to use the FTP (and other) protocols.  The FTP protocol is only for getting files from point A to B and perhaps minimal directory management on a server.  It is technically possible to execute SSH commands with SFTP (FTP over SSH), but not implemented in the **NppFTP** plugin.

What **NppExec** is (from the documentation):

- NppExec is an intermediary between Notepad++ and external tool/compiler. It allows to run external tool/compiler directly from Notepad++.
- NppExec is a Console window which can show the running process'es output, and can redirect the Console window's input to the running process (with some limitations).
- NppExec is an interpreter of its own internal commands. NppExec can execute several commands one after another (so-called NppExec's script) from its "Execute..." dialog and can execute single command directly from its Console window.